# Unable to give admin rights back to main account Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, user-accounts, administrator, guest-account

I use HP notebook and my os is windows 8.1. Someone made my guest account as administrator and removed administrator rights from my main account. So, I m not able to access anything from my main account. There is no option to give admin rights back to my main account, because the current admin account is guest account. I m completely locked out here. Someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/lost-administrative-rights-in-windows

Comment: If you already have a Microsoft account, you should still be able to log into it and continue. Or else, I can provide you a different way, if you got a bootable iso.

Comment: The problem is am not able to create new user accounts also

Comment: @Epoxy All my accounts are local acoount, I dont have a bootable iso, but i have the recovery partition.. is there anything that can be done with that?

Comment: Yes, you can recover with the system recovery system of course. Or else, if you can burn a small bootable iso and do a small trick, you can boot into windows and access system account to add a new account or event to change your account type/role. What is the windows edition?

Comment: @Epoxy Mine is windows 8.1,  and could you please elaborate on this " burn a small bootable iso and do a small trick"?

Comment: Yes, which edition. Like basic, pro? Anyway, I'll add an answer here.

Comment: mine is Home edition

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed a Windows before? If not call your geek cousin. The next steps require a bit of tech savvy-ness.

Download https://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html burn it, the guest account still lets you do it.
Create a partition empty on your disk something above 20GB just enough to hold Windows.
Install a fresh Windows there, then log into the fresh install and regain access of your files.

If you don't have a Windows installation disc you can download a Linux Image (Damn Small Linux for instance is only 50 Mb, although a bit intimidating for new users, but no worries all you are going to do, is copy your files from the windows user and saving them in a usb or external disc to rescue your data). After that you can make factory restore in your PC or laptop, and have a fresh start, consult your manufacturer for info on that.

Unfortunately as you might have already experiment there is no way to get off this unusual error. Other then a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you may have to try if there are absolutely no other options. Like no recovery options work. This does not work if BitLocker is enabled and UEFI is in use.

1. Download and burn any Linux Live CD distribution to a cd. You can select one from [here](https://livecdlist.com/).
2. Make sure bios is legacy. Boot mode (priority of the devices) must be cd/dvd. Do necessary changes to BIOS and save the settings.
3. Now, boot from the CD. You may be able to set up a USB if you prefer. I am not explaining it here.
4. Once you boot to Linux, you have to do the following change. You can either use terminal or a folder browser to browse to Windows files and do some renaming.
5. Go to C:\Windows\System32
6. Find cmd.exe and rename it to cmd.exe.bak
7. Find and rename sethc.exe to cmd.exe
8. Now, restart the system.
9. Boot into Windows.
10. Press shift 5 times (sticky keys).
11. Now you will see a command prompt opening up.
12. You can now run netplwiz command. This is the easiest. Double click the user to view properties and to see the membership options. Use the Group membership tab to change back to admin. You cannot use lusrmgr.msc as Windows is a home edition.
    Or, else use this following command to reset the role of the previous account. As some editions don't provide this mmc.
    net localgroup administrators name_of_new_user /add
13. If you want to create a new user, and add him to the admin group,
    net user /add name_of_new_user password
    net localgroup administrators name_of_new_user /add

Don't forget to change cmd.exe to sethc.exe and cmd.exe.bak to cmd.exe (use the Linux live cd)